# Add query params after building the URIComponents

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using a UriComponentsBuilder to create my GET request endpoint and it works fine.

But I am trying to make it reusable such that I can pass in as many request params and

path variables as I want without limiting it. This is fine for path variables since I

can pass as many params as I want as a map inside buildAndExpand.

But how could I do it for request param too? Please advice.

This is what I am currently doing but this is not reusable.

```
  public Map get(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e) {

    String url = "domain.com/get/{a}/{b}";

    String endPoint = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
            .queryParam("c" ,c)
            .queryParam("d" ,d)
            .queryParam("e" ,e)
            .buildAndExpand(
                    new HashMap<String, String>() {{
                      put("a", a);
                      put("b", b);
                    }}
            ).toUriString();

    return restTemplate.getForEntity(endPoint, Map.class);
  }
```

I want to instead pull out the endpoint creation as a separate method as follows.

```
  private UriComponents getUriComponent(String url, Map<String, String> params) {
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url);
    return builder.buildAndExpand(params);
  }
```

This would work fine for the path params a and b.
But how can I take in an argument here for b,c,e too which are query params.
Or some other suggestions to keep it dynamic. So I can pass in 5 queryParam for one request
and 10 queryParam for another without having to rewrite the UriComponentsBuilder each time.

Please note that preferably, I do **not** want to modify the url to like the following for this.

```
String url = "domain.com/get/{a}/{b}?c={c}&d={d}&e={e}";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, using `UriComponentsBuilder` you can add new parameters to the URL.

```java
String old = UriComponentsBuilder.newInstance()
        .scheme("http")
        .host("localhost")
        .queryParam("a", "b")
        .build()
        .toUriString();
// probably other method
String res = UriComponentsBuilder
        .fromHttpUrl(old)
        .queryParam("new", "new")
        .build()
        .toUriString();

System.out.println(res); // output: http://localhost?a=b&new=new
```

If you need to add params stored in a `Map`, create an instance of `org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap` and call `queryParams` or `replaceQueryParams` depending on your needs to add parameters or replace parameters.

```java
// I've changed method signature to accept Map<String, List<String>>, but you can leave just String and wrap String to a singleton list
private UriComponents getUriComponent(String url, Map<String, List<String>> params) {
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
            .queryParams(new LinkedMultiValueMap<>(params));
    return builder.build();
}
```